# Why does Wikipedia state that the Solar System has one unconfirmed planet?

Tags: the-sun, planet, pluto, 9th-planet

I was looking at [exoplanets on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiplanetary_systems), and found this surprising information:

[image: Sun stats]

The table states that the Sun has 8 planets (obviously) and one unconfirmed planet. Why is this here? I think it's Planet Nine, but I also have underlying thoughts that this planet is Pluto, a disputed dwarf/real planet. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was a [rather recent (16 January 2021) change](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_multiplanetary_systems&type=revision&diff=1000634173&oldid=999729700) to that wiki page made by a user named Mariofeds, who does not have a wikipedia user page and who has just one contribution to wikipedia.

It may well have been vandalism.

The associated talk page explicitly excludes adding the hypothetical Planet Nine as an unconfirmed planet. In line with this discussion, the number of planets listed for the solar system had remained as eight confirmed, none unconfirmed for a long time.